# filter the model not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

```
def index
if params[:price_id].present? 
  if params[:price_id]
    @prications = Prication.where(price_id: params[:price_id])
    @dresses = @prications.map(&:dress)
  end
end
else
@dresses=Dress.order(id: :desc)
   if params[:search]
  @search_term = params[:search]
  @dresses = @dresses.search_by(@search_term)
end
end

private

def dress_attributes
 dress_attributes = params.require(:dress).permit(:name,:email,:phone,:description,:image,:image2,:price_ids)
end
```

and

### new.html.erb

```
Price:  <%= f.collection_select :price_ids, Price.all, :id,:name, {prompt: true} %>
```

and in

### index.html.erb

```
   <h6>Shop By Price</h6>
      <% Price.all.each do |price| %>
      <%= link_to price.name,dresses_path(params.merge(price_id: price.id)) , class: "#{'shadow' if params[:price_id].to_i == price.id}" %><br>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

### price model

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prications,dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dresses, through: :prications
end
```

### prication model

```
class Prication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dress
  belongs_to :price
end
```

when i press any of the price name it not filtered why it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you an extra end between the if condition

you have this:

```
def index
if params[:price_id].present? 
  if params[:price_id]
    @prications = Prication.where(price_id: params[:price_id])
    @dresses = @prications.map(&:dress)
  end
end
else
@dresses=Dress.order(id: :desc)
   if params[:search]
  @search_term = params[:search]
  @dresses = @dresses.search_by(@search_term)
end
end
```

And it should be like this:

```
def index
  if params[:price_id].present? 
    if params[:price_id]
      @prications = Prication.where(price_id: params[:price_id])
      @dresses = @prications.map(&:dress)
    end 
  else
    @dresses=Dress.order(id: :desc)
    if params[:search]
      @search_term = params[:search]
      @dresses = @dresses.search_by(@search_term)
    end
  end
end
```